# Boot from an empty HD

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, blank-screen

I have a brand new Solid State Drive (empty) and another Hard Disk Drive (files and content)

I want to install Windows 7 and I have the CD.

When I turn my computer on it won't boot, just the monitor is blank - can't even get into DOS.

Specs:

```
ASUS USB 3.0 Motherboard
ATI Radeon HD GPU
60gb SSD x1
1tb HD x1
DVDRW Drive
```

I have Windows 7 and I want to install it on my SSD. How can I do this?

Comment: Insert the DVD into the drive, boot - and the magic begins. If not, check the boot order in BIOS.

Comment: What is your boot configuration? Make sure it's set to boot from DVD first, not the empty SSD, which is what it sounds like it's trying to do. @Aki is saying this in regards to the boot order in BIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the initial POST on the screen when you first power up you should see something about "Boot Device" or "Boot Order", etc... This will let you select the device you want to boot off of (CD/DVD) without having to change anything in the BIOS settings.

Comment: But the screen is blank. It just appears blank, nothing on it.

Comment: Do you here any sounds or beeping like you normally would when you first power up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go into the bios settings and set the dvd drive to the primary boot device, then restart the machine and it should boot into the windows install cd.